# How can check if heartbeat is disabled?

Tags: heartbeat-api

I want a code to check if the heartbeat is disabled from a WordPress site or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [heartbeat API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/heartbeat-api/) is essentially a script that is included in your site's head. It performs calls back to the server. So, to disable the heartbeat the script must not be enqueued. And you can check whether a script is enqueued with [`wp_script_is`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is). Like this:

```
if (wp_script_is ('heartbeat')) ...
```