# Disabled Heartbeat but i think it's still working. Is there a plugin or script to check it?

Tags: heartbeat-api

I just disabled Heartbeat with the plugin Heartbeat control and also adding this script in function.php of my child-theme

```
add_action( 'init', 'stop_heartbeat', 1 );
function stop_heartbeat() {
wp_deregister_script('heartbeat');
}
```

But i think it's still working and some plugin is overriding it. I still have large cpu spike while the site is in mantainance mode. Is there a function or action that i can use to check if this worked ?

Comment: Can I ask why you disabled heartbeat? I also see you tagged your question as `wordpress.com`, are you hosted on wordpress.com? WP.com support is offtopic here, if you're paying WP.com for your site you should speak with their support, otherwise, remove that tag

Comment: Sorry it was unintended, i removed that tag.

Comment: And the answers could be [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/297098/how-can-check-if-heartbeat-is-disabled?rq=1)

Comment: @JoJo I assume you're disabling heartbeat to prevent CPU spikes? How did you identify that it was the Hearbeat script that was doing this? Or did you just google general cpu reduction articles and found heartbeat in a listicle? The best thing you can do to reduce CPU is to just do fewer things on each page, and deactivate plugin/replace them with faster plugins